# SQL Select * FROM table where date is dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssms, prepared-statement

I'm trying to run a parametrized SELECT query on a table, where date is equal to my @date stored in a variable and for some reason it does not work:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME;
set @date = '09/01/2022';

select * from dba.hello where datum = @date
```

This works the way that I want to, but when i try to parametrize the query as follows:

```
 declare @table_name nvarchar(255);
 set @table_name = 'dba.hello';

 DECLARE @date DATETIME;
 set @date = '09/01/2022';

 exec('select * from '+@table_name+' where datum = '+@date)
```

I'm getting this error: Parse error at line: 1, column: 58: Incorrect syntax near '2022'.

Does anyone know what could be the issue, please?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want/need a dynamic table name in the first place?

Comment: I want to run a procedure from PowerApps that will send input parameters into my procedure, such as date and table name. It works just fine with my other proc, in which I run unpivot and copy statements from staging tables into my final tables, but there is some issue when trying to make some statements with dates in it

Comment: Yes, but again, *why* do you want/need a dynamic table name? This is generally the sign of a design flaw; such as using a table's name to represent something that should be stored in a column.

Comment: By the way, it is always better to write dates in ISO-format.Like '20211029' or '2021-10-29' (29 October 2021)

Comment: With a `(small)datetime` even `yyyy-MM-dd` isn't safe, @Sergey . :(

Comment: I can't think of a more efficient way to deal with the issue of running a delete procedure from an application, where I select my variables (date and table name) in a SQL server where I have several tables. Plus, unfortunately, it is not desired to change the design at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to, just like any statement, parametrise your dynamic statement. If you do that, you have no problems. I also split your schema and table names into 2 variables and *safely* inject them:

```sql
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname,
        @TableName sysname;

SET @SchemaName = N'dba';
SET @TableName = N'Hello';

DECLARE @date datetime = '20220109'; --Should this not be a date is it's only a date?

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' WHERE datum = @date;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@date datetime', @date;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!:) I see it's better to run the exec statements this way since they are more clear compared to exec(' code '), will probably change my other param. procedures to this!

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't be using the `EXEC({SQL})` method, @MedvidekPu . Put the statement into a variable, and then execute that using `sys.sp_executesql`. Then you can parametrise the statements when you need to with ease.